# MongoDB aggregate query to find Objects containing at least one match from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write a query for my movies mongo database which has two collection, movie and ratings which the following structure:
movie

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb3e0a9dac8ab419c430e94"),
    "MovieId" : 3,
    "MovieTitle" : "Four Rooms (1995)",
    // and other unrelated fields
}
```

ratings:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb3e049dac8ab419c4223ed"),
    "user_id" : 450,
    "item_id" : 172,
    "rating" : 4,
    "timestamp" : 882372103
}
```

where MovieId == item_id.
I need to find the top-10 movie titles of all movies with at least one review rating less than 3.

Here is my attempt to find the id of top 10 movie that works:

```
db.ratings.aggregate(
  [
    {"$group":
      {
        _id: {item_id:"$item_id"},
        ratingAverage: {$avg: "$rating"}
      }
    } ,{$sort : { ratingAverage: -1 } }, {$limit : 10}
  ]
)
```

Here is my attempt to find the top 10 movie with at least rating less than 3.

```
db.ratings.aggregate([
  {"$match":
    "rating":{"$lt":3}
  },
  {"$group":
    {
      _id: "$item_id",
      ratingAverage: {$avg: "$rating"}
    }
  },
  {$lookup:
  {
    "from": "movie",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "MovieId",
    "as": "movie_details"
  }},{$sort : { ratingAverage: -1 } }, {$limit : 10}

])
```

This return:

```
ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'rating' must be an accumulator object",
    "code" : 40234,
    "codeName" : "Location40234"
```

Can someone please give me some suggestion on how to go about this

Answer (score 1):

you should change your `$match` part like this:

```
...
{"$match":
    { "rating":{"$lt":3} }
},
...
```

you probably forgot to put `{}` around the query for `$match`

Comment: Thank you ! It just got rid of the syntax problem. However, I failed to get the top 10 movies out of this query. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @K.U remove the first `$match` part, instead, get a list of `item_id`'s of all movies that  have a movie_rating less than 3, then use `$filter` to filter all movies that are in this list, then you can get the rating average in this filtered list of ratings and get the top ten.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't write a sample aggregate query for you, because I would have to generate a fake dataset to be able to test the query myself, but if you tried and could not accomplish this yourself, you can upload a mongodump somewhere and put a link here so I can write the query based on that data.